# Window freezes on opening cloud files

Tags: windows-explorer, freeze, onedrive, cloud-storage, icloud

I am running OneDrive on my computer, and for some reason, whenever I try to open a file on iCloud Drive or OneDrive (either personal or business) using file explorer on my computer, the window will freeze up for about a minute.  After this time, the window will unfreeze and work perfectly normally until I click somewhere in the window again.  It will do this only in the cloud folders.

The issue can't be anything to do with the syncing, as I can open files and folders normally from PowerShell.

This happens for both right- and left-clicks.

Uninstalling and reinstalling OneDrive works for a bit, but the issue comes back after a reboot.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found, after contacting Microsoft Support and our help desk to no avail, that the issue was with iCloud Drive.  As long as I was trying to access files, if I had iCloud Drive downloaded and signed in but not running on my computer, the glitch would happen.

Either opening iCloud Drive or uninstalling it makes OneDrive work great!

I opted for the latter (as iCloud Drive takes up inordinate amounts of memory).

Comment: Thanks, uninstalling iCloud helped for me!

Comment: Thanks for posting this; my mom was having the same problem and this solved it.